# C# cannot find class - The type or namespace name 'GradeBook' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

im completley new with c# and cannot seem to find the issue here. I have two .cs files in the same project, have set start up project etc. But one of the classes from the first .cs file is not found by the .cs that is supposed to run the program

File1:

```
using System;

public class GradeBookTest
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GradeBook myGradeBook = new GradeBook();

        Console.WriteLine("Initial course name is: '{0}'\n", myGradeBook.CourseName);

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter course name:");
        myGradeBook.CourseName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        myGradeBook.DisplayMessage();
    }
}
```

File2:

```
using System;

public class GradeBook
{
private string courseName;

public string CourseName
{
    get
    {
        return courseName;
    }
    set
    {
        courseName = value;
    }
}

public void DisplayMessage()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the grade book for \n{0}!", CourseName);
}
```

}

And this is just an example from my book, but need to figure out why its not working. It is the class GradeBook that the error message appears from when im trying to create and object in "GradeBook myGradeBook = new GradeBook();

Comment: What is the Namespace of the files? If you haven't set any I'd suggest you use one and try adding the proper using for it :)

Comment: Where is the namespace? probably if you add the namespace it will work

Comment: Did you google it?

Comment: It seems you are missing namespaces. Take a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx

Comment: make it static.

Comment: **Please** - do **not** make it static. Dude, this guy is new to C# and you suggest him one of the worst practices in software development - make it static if you can not use it ... *sigh* ... by the way this wouldn't help if he got no using for the namespace

Comment: I'll quote my textbook: There’s a special relationship between classes that are compiled in the same project. By default, such classes are considered to be in the same namespace. A using directive is not required when one class in a namespace uses another in the same namespace. @TripleEEE

Comment: @TripleEEE See the comment above, something happend with the tagging

Comment: @DouglasPettersson Hi Take a look at this maybe: *Whether or not you explicitly declare a namespace in a C# source file, the compiler adds a default namespace. This unnamed namespace, sometimes called the global namespace, is present in every file. Any identifier in the global namespace is available for use in a named namespace.* - From MSDN. Well I guess your book puts both classes into the same file, this will lead to both having the same Namespace. Elsewise they probably won't

Comment: Couldn't edit my last comment - Me beeing dump - the file **will** be in the same Namespace - the so called "global one" - I copied your code and it runs perfectly fine if I use it without namespaces beeing defined... :/ Does your Code run, if you define namespaces, or put both classes into the same file?

Comment: @TripleEEE For some reason, no. I get an error that it cannot find the namespace either..  
The type or namespace name 'GradeBookNameSpace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: *It works when i compiled everything to one file in a new project

Comment: @DouglasPettersson Huh,... Say: Are both files in the same project? Or are they maybe in different ones? This would explain it...

Comment: @DouglasPettersson I got another idea,... If both files are in the same project, you might have changed the "build process" to "none" by accident... Would you check in your _project browser_? - Click on you file and see if in your _properties window_ the buildprocess is set to "compile", If not, you class won't be recognized in any case, because there is nothing the compiler will compile. *lazy thing*

Comment: @TripleEEE In the project folder there are two different folders for each of the files, should they be in the same one?

Comment: It is set to compile. This is weird

Comment: @DouglasPettersson If you use default settings by VS, a folder will "change" you namespace, by adding *.foldername* to the existing namespace. But if you define your own namespace that shouldn't be  a problem either... Maybe you can edit your original post, and add a Picture (snapshot) or your project browser, maybe this will give me some hint. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not have the `using` declaration at the top of your File1. You need to tell the compiler to 'include' other dependent files, specifically the class file containing `GradeBook` (File2). Here is the fix to File1:

```
using System;
using GradeBookNameSpace.GradeBook;

public class GradeBookTest
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    GradeBook myGradeBook = new GradeBook();

    Console.WriteLine("Initial course name is: '{0}'\n", myGradeBook.CourseName);

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter course name:");
    myGradeBook.CourseName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();

    myGradeBook.DisplayMessage();
    }
}
```

I write `GradeBookNameSpace` there because I don't know the namespace of your `GradeBook` class. You can find this by looking at the

```
namespace NameSpaceName
{
}
```

Which surrounds your class. You may not need this though. I'm not sure it could depend on your file structure. Just try `using GradeBook` first.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You do not need a namespace in particular. Your code gets a namespace from you project which defines a namespace, if you don't define one in your file. Just wanted to add this, though I'd say you're right. Defining namespaces is common for some reasons.

Comment: Yes that is true and why I mentioned that it depends on your file structure. Therefore, if he adds the `using GradeBook` directive it should work fine.